# Where can I find GIS files that shows the 11 nations of the USA?

Tags: data, united-states

This book [describes the cultural boundaries](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-11-nations-of-the-united-states-2015-7) that define America.  At least one person has created what seems to be a GIS style map from this.

Does anyone know where I can locate these files?

[image]

Comment: Ask the Author? http://colinwoodard.blogspot.ca/2015/02/population-figures-for-american-nations.html twitter @woodardcolin built on census data has changed many times.

Comment: Might want to check out the open data stackexchange http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ask the author for the data source or a map

Comment: If asking the author doesn't work and you're feeling unusually reverse engineer-y, you could write a program to determine county list from color.